# 7 way light bulb combinations

Tags: combinatorics, word-problem

I am having trouble with this question as I am not sure I am approaching it in the correct manor.

> A so-called 7-way lamp has three 60-watt bulbs which may be turned on one or two
>   or all three at a time, and a large bulb which may be turned to 100 watts, 200 watts
>   or 300 watts. How many different light intensities can the lamp be set to give if the
>   completely off position is not included?

Firstly I am not too sure what the ref to a seven way light bulb is from what I have google I have assumed it means that the intensity of the bulb can be varied with 7 different intensity's and I am assuming that as the bulbs can be turned on separately then the intensity for each can be varied individually.

So my working are as follows

If I think of a single bulb on it own, the I am going to have $^7C_1=7$ different intensities.

Now if I switch on another bulb so now I would have $^7C_1*^7C_1=49$

a brief reasoning for this is as follows:

$B_n=n^{th}$ Bulb

$I_n=n^{th}$ Intensity

If I set $B_1$ to an intensity of $I_1$ then turned on $B_2$ and adjust the intensity of $B_2$ from $I_1$ to $I_7$ then I would form the following combinations

$I_1,I_1$

$I_1,I_2$

.

.

.

.

$I_1,I_7$

So if I apply this to all for 2 bulbs I would get $49$ different intensities.

Applying same logic again to all three $60W$ bulbs then I would have 343 different intensities.

Now if I then add the $100W$ bulb to this I would get $343+7=350$ different intensities.

If I then apply this to varying the bulb power for $200W$ and $300W$ then the number of intensity's I would get now would be:

$$No.intensity=343+7*3=364$$

Iv tried to think of it as I would be operating the switch myself, but am just not 100% that this is correct, is there a flaw with my working or how I have approached this?

Comment: Where in the problem does it say anything about a “seven way light bulb?” There is a seven-way _lamp_ that consists of three single-setting bulbs and a three-way bulb. The three single-setting bulbs taken as a group are effectively a second three-way bulb.

Comment: This is my confusion what is a "7 way lamp" my information came from a wiki article I read, which was for a 3 way lamp. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-way_lamp

Comment: The problem is self-contained. It describes exactly how the lamp operates, which is all that you need to know to solve the problem. What it’s called is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: In any case, even if there were such a thing as a seven-way light bulb, you’ve seriously overcounted the possible intensities. Many of those $7^3$ combinations that you’ve counted produce the same light intensity.

Comment: I realised this, which is why I am now trying to see, how I would excluded theses.

Comment: It’s fairly easy to count unique intensities if the settings are spaced uniformly, otherwise, I’d try using generating functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so if there are n devices with k positions, there are $k^n$ possibilities.
The possible intensities for the first three bulbs are $0$, $60$, $120$ and $180$ (4 possibilities). The three-way bulb has 3 positions and a off position, so 4 positions in total. So there are $4\cdot 4 = 16$ possibilities. You remove the position completely off and you get $15$ positions.

Comment: Ah okay it just clicked, my trouble was what a 7 way lamp was, I miss read the wiki article completely, thank you for the help.

Comment: For a truly complete answer, you also need to argue that all 15 of those combinations produce unique intensities.